# How to paint on Form at Design Time?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If I have a `UserControl` and override `OnPaint` I can do what I want there and when I add that `UserControl` to a `Form` in designer in Visual Studio 2010 the `OnPaint` method is called and the user control is painted and viewed in the designer as I want.

The question is can I do that with a `Form` not with an `UserControl`? How can I draw on `Form` that designer shows them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The designer creates your form's base class; it doesn't create your form itself.
Any code in your form class itself will not run in the designer.

You need to make a separate base class that inherits `Form` and paints itself.
You will then see the painting in the designer of any form that inherits the base class.