# Drawing a rectangle on a form in C#

Tags: c#, graphics

How can I draw a rectangle on a form in C# which is visible to me when I am working on the form i.e. putting buttons or text boxes on the form. I am using the following way to create a rectangle on a form but it is visible only when I run the form instead I want it to be visible at design time.

My code is as below:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{    
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    g.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Inch;
    Pen red1 = new Pen(Color.Green, 0.03f);
    g.DrawLine(blackpen, 1, 2, 1, 3);
    g.DrawLine(red1, 1,2, 3,2 );
    g.DrawLine(red1, 1, 3, 3, 3);
    g.DrawLine(red1, 3, 2, 3, 3);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to paint on Form at Design Time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694171/how-to-paint-on-form-at-design-time)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach `Paint` event to the form.

Just add the following statement in constructor.

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);
```

and change the method signature to

```
void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
```

Comment: @ Asif it is giving an error: No overload for 'OnPaint' matches delegate 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler'what to do?

Comment: you need to change the method signature to void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

Comment: @ Asif it now gave another error:line_draw.Form1.OnPaint(object, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is incorrect -- the problem lies somewhere else. Please see the accepted answer in the duplicate I linked to.

Comment: @ Asif The error is gone but the rectangle is visible at runtime only.Is my method for drawing rectangle correct or not.

Comment: I think consider the @Henizi recommendation